# Are the empty set and limit ordinals the only fixpoints of the big union operator?

Tags: set-theory

Let $S$ be a set. Suppose $\bigcup S = S$. Must $S$ be empty or a limit ordinal? It is easy to see that no successor ordinal can be equal to its own union. So, another way of asking the question is, there a set $S$ that is not an ordinal such that $\bigcup S = S$?

Comment: I would say the empty set is a limit ordinal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  For instance, $S$ could be $V_\alpha$ for any limit ordinal $\alpha$.  There are lots of other possibilities too--for example, $S$ could be $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\{\emptyset\}\},\dots\}$.